# Ant Fileset to Comma Separated List

Tags: ant, osgi

I'm trying to pass a fileset to a macrodef, and have the macro generate a comma separated list of the classes.  More over, I also need to change the list to contain java package & class names instead of "/" delimmited names.

We're using Ant, OSGi, and bnd and what I'm ultimately trying to do is create an entry in the Manifest that contains the fully qualified class name of each entry of the fileset.

End Goal example:

```
Manifest-Entry: org.foo.bar.ClassOne, org.foo.bar.ClassTo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using the Ant [`pathconvert` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) with a nested mapper, for example:

```
<property name="classes" location="classes" />
<fileset dir="${classes}" id="classes" />

<pathconvert dirsep="." refid="classes" property="manifest.entry" pathsep=", ">
    <mapper type="regexp" from="${classes}/(.*).class" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<echo message="Manifest-Entry: ${manifest.entry}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bnd, you could also try using the `${classes}` macro in the `bnd` file.